# Cognos: filter alternative?

Tags: filter, cognos

I've defined a report in **Cognos Report Studio**.

I've also exposed this report in **IBM BAM Business Spaces**. I've used Report Viewer widget for that.

This widget allows end users to remove filters defined for the report. The data security is preserved (FGS applied), but they can access irrelevant data for specific report.

I would like to disable this (removing filters). Unfortunately this build-in widget is not allowing that.

As workaround I'm trying to use some other technique than filters to limit the data. I was trying to apply the filtering within the slicer.
My data is quite flat, and the data item I want to filter is not defined as dimension. That's probably the reason why it's not working for me.
I have a table with multiple columns.

My slicer definition:

```
filter([A_Events Query Subject].[ATracking_Events].[Status Code], 
          [A_Events Query Subject].[A_Events].[Status Code] = 'Q')
```

Anyway, all data (not filtered) are shown as a result.

Any idea how this can be solved?

Comment: Can you modify the Framework Manager model? You can embed the filters in the model layer and the end user would have no way of removing them.

Comment: Hi Johnsonium, not really. This model is used for multiple reports. I would prefer not to create a model for each report.